# How can i get all the Contacts info without ask for specific field ?

Tags: android

When i ask for some field on the contact i need to ask each field alone

for example if i need to ask the id and the name i need to write it

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();   
 Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

 String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID ));
 String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

But in this case i need to write long code that make an access to each of the contact field and check if this field is fill up.

Is there some way to avoid this and get all the contact info at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
for (String colName:cur.getColumnNames())
 {
    String a = colName;
    String b = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(colName));

    //now you have the name of the column in variable a, and the data in variable b
 }
```